# Amplifier output wattage and speaker wattage

Tags: amplifier, speakers, rms

I have a Creative Inspire M2600. The Satellite speakers have broken and I have to use another 2 speakers. A note [here](http://support.creative.com/kb/ShowArticle.aspx?sid=56402) says the RMS Value of Satellites is 6 W each. It is bit difficult to get speakers in my area. Can I use speakers with wattage more than 6W (10 - 15 W) without damaging the amplifier circuit ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two criteria your speakers have to meet:

Their impedance must fall within the acceptable range in your amplifier's spec'.

Their RMS and peak power must be the same or higher than the amplifier's RMS and peak power output.

Bear in mind that having the volume anywhere below maximum is delivering less amplifier power to your speakers. So you may well be driving them with much less than 6 W all the time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use speakers with wattage more than 6W if its resistance is same as original speakers. In this case, the load on the amplifier will not change.